# in local jupyter lab, in js, how to call py meth and get its result and show result in html

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter

I try following code, but result still null

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML

def get():
    return "in py"

html_content = """
<div id="ctn">null</div>
<script>
let ce = document.querySelector("#ctn");
const callback = {
  iopub: {
    output: (data) => {
      // this will print a message in browser console
      // console.log('hello in console')
      // this will insert the execution result into "result_output" div
      ce.innerHTML = data.content.text
    }
  }
};
const kernel = Jupyter.notebook.kernel
kernel.execute("get()", callback);
</script>
"""
display(HTML(html_content))
```